# Can we move VM's to another region with out Site recovery in Azure?

Tags: azure

Is there a way to move Azure VM from one region to another without using Azure Site Recovery

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can but not supported by Microsoft or recommended and takes time, lots of work and cost.

Summary:

-Copy VHD to other region

-Recreate VM in other region

2 examples of the process:

https://www.obungi.com/2017/07/21/how-to-copy-an-azure-vm-from-region-a-to-region-b/
https://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/11/16/migrating-azure-virtual-machines-to-another-region/

Comment: define not supported. I don't see how copying vhd is not supported

Comment: That was just a summary, they are a lot of other components involve for a successful migration. Azure Site Recovery migration is the only migration option  that Microsoft supports that doesn't mean there are not other processes. If something fails in ASR migration there is a team to look over the whole process, manually migration you will have to identify the component that fail and file a ticket just for component not the process.